# Exception while dispatching incoming RPC call java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPCRequest

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, gwt, rpc

I have GWT page with Hibernate and MySQL setup already.  I'm running it in SuperDev mode and here is the error I get after compiling the page:

```
 [WARN] Exception while dispatching incoming RPC call
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPCRequest.<init>(Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;[Ljava/lang/Object;Lcom/google/gwt/user/server/rpc/SerializationPolicy;)V
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPCCopy_GWT15.decodeRequest(RPCCopy_GWT15.java:278)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPCCopy.decodeRequest(RPCCopy.java:136)
    at net.sf.gilead.gwt.PersistentRemoteService.processCall(PersistentRemoteService.java:143)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processPost(RemoteServiceServlet.java:305)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.doPost(AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.java:62)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:755)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:686)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:557)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1086)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:428)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1020)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.RequestLogHandler.handle(RequestLogHandler.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:370)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:489)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:960)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1021)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:865)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:668)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
[ERROR] 500 - POST /atlas_emergency_status_page/DBService (127.0.0.1) 57 bytes
   Request headers
      Host: 127.0.0.1:8888
      Connection: keep-alive
      Content-Length: 162
      X-GWT-Module-Base: http://127.0.0.1:8888/atlas_emergency_status_page/
      X-GWT-Permutation: BE75887428AD071A73976B7011B26FBF
      Origin: http://127.0.0.1:8888
      User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.111 Safari/537.36
      Content-Type: text/x-gwt-rpc; charset=UTF-8
      Accept: */*
      Referer: http://127.0.0.1:8888/ATLAS_Emergency_Status_Page.html
      Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
      Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,fr-CH;q=0.6,fr;q=0.4,ka;q=0.2,ru;q=0.2
   Response headers
      Content-Type: text/plain
```

what might be causing this?

**Edit:**

Here is my **web.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
         http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" version="2.5">

  <!-- Servlets -->
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>greetServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>ch.cern.atlas.emergency.status.server.GreetingServiceImpl</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>greetServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/atlas_emergency_status_page/greet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <!-- Default page to serve -->
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>ATLAS_Emergency_Status_Page.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

  <!-- Servlets -->
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>LoginService</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>ch.cern.atlas.emergency.status.server.LoginServiceImpl</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>LoginService</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/atlas_emergency_status_page/LoginService</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>DBService</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>ch.cern.atlas.emergency.status.server.DBServiceImpl</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>DBService</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/atlas_emergency_status_page/DBService</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its' a conflict with your version of gwt and the libraries you are using. On your stack trace, you are using "gilead" and an old version of "hibernate4gwt". This version require GWT1.5.

You shoud upgrade these libraries to be compatible with the version of gwt you have

Comment: thanks for your response. I can't find these libraries in build path, what would they be called exactly?

Comment: gilead and "PersistentRemoteService" are not included in GWT. it's an opensource to help with the integration of hibernate in a gwt application. You must have a dependency on this project somewhere :-)

Comment: I would say stop using gilead as it is no longer maintained. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11683838/gwthibernategilead-is-not-working

Comment: @ElHoss, now I'm getting this error (after trying yo change the libs in build path) Initial SessionFactory creation failed.org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to get the default Bean Validation factory.
I have hibernate-validator-4.0.2.jar and javax-validation.jar libs in build path, but still not working...

Comment: alright, solved by disabling validator in properties :-)

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to tell without seeing your web.xml and RPC classes

maybe you have mistake in web.xml RPC servlet declaration or RPC service is not implemented correctly

Comment: I added web.xml file. Exactly which RPC file do you need to see? DBService.java, DBServiceAsync.java and DBServiceImpl.java?

Comment: I do not think, that the problem is related to the web.xml. If you have problems related to the web.xml, you will get a 404 or the the server does not start (ClassNotFounException). You have got an error code 500. I would debug the server implementation. It looks like that there is something going wrong.

Comment: @ElHoss, what exactly do you mean by server implementation? Like DBServiceImpl class? Thanks for at least narrowing the research field

Comment: Which version of GWT are you using?

Comment: @ElHoss, GWT SDK 2.6.0

Comment: The class RPCCopy and RPCCopy_GWT15 are not included in GWT 2.6. They have been removed with GWT 2.0. So, it looks like your server code needs to be updated. Hope that helps.

Comment: @ElHoss, ok, this now clarifies situation, as to why it isn't working and why I wasn't able to find any information about this error whatsoever. Now, last question - how will I be able to resolve this issue? I tried adding these classes to build path, but didn't help.

Comment: @ElHoss, How can I check at what point these classes are called in server code?